# IOS Swift code pin map marker after enter region

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swift2, core-location

I would like to pin the map marker in which region that I entered but the method didEnterRegion() on locationManager is not provide the latitude and longitude. The method didEnterRegion is works properly. I've tried many ways to get the latitude and longitude but its didn't work.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region:CLRegion) {
    self.claimPoint.hidden = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called GeoFencing and it would never provide you with one coordinate. You see, it checks if you are INSIDE an area (mostly a circle around a point you've defined). So, you can never get a coordination from these methods. The only thing you can obtain is the center and radius of the region. You should define the persist the region somehow and when entered the region, query you regions by their IDs and find the respective region, then you'l have the center and radius. If you need a more accurate location info, use other methods instead.